# How to print first column of row along with specific pattern?

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract a pattern along with printing the starting string of the line.
Input

```
Saureus1000(37 genes,10 taxa):  Saureus08BA02176_00020(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus1269_00069(Saureus1269) Saureus170_00062(Saureus170) Saureus71193_00020(Saureus71193) SaureusED133_00019(SaureusED133) SaureusED98_00019(SaureusED98) SaureusLGA251_00019(SaureusLGA251) SaureusN305_00605(SaureusN305) SaureusRF122_00019(SaureusRF122) SaureusST398_00020(SaureusST398) Saureus08BA02176_01763(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus08BA02176_01805(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus08BA02176_01808(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus1269_01194(Saureus1269) Saureus1269_01237(Saureus1269) Saureus1269_01240(Saureus1269) Saureus71193_01635(Saureus71193) Saureus71193_01678(Saureus71193) Saureus71193_01681(Saureus71193) SaureusED133_01798(SaureusED133) SaureusED133_01840(SaureusED133) SaureusED133_01843(SaureusED133) SaureusED98_01777(SaureusED98) SaureusED98_01821(SaureusED98) SaureusED98_01824(SaureusED98) SaureusLGA251_01748(SaureusLGA251) SaureusLGA251_01790(SaureusLGA251) SaureusLGA251_01793(SaureusLGA251) SaureusN305_00013(SaureusN305) SaureusN305_00016(SaureusN305) SaureusN305_00059(SaureusN305) SaureusRF122_01807(SaureusRF122) SaureusRF122_01848(SaureusRF122) SaureusRF122_01851(SaureusRF122) SaureusST398_01884(SaureusST398) SaureusST398_01927(SaureusST398) SaureusST398_01930(SaureusST398)
Saureus1001(35 genes,12 taxa):  Saureus08BA02176_01441(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus1269_02301(Saureus1269) Saureus1269_02527(Saureus1269) Saureus71193_01310(Saureus71193) SaureusED98_01421(SaureusED98) SaureusED98_01424(SaureusED98) SaureusN305_02184(SaureusN305) SaureusN305_02188(SaureusN305) SaureusN305_02190(SaureusN305) SaureusRF122_01383(SaureusRF122) SaureusRF122_01386(SaureusRF122) SaureusST398_01476(SaureusST398) Saureus08BA02176_01442(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus08BA02176_01443(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus08BA02176_01445(Saureus08BA02176) Saureus1269_02302(Saureus1269) Saureus1269_02529(Saureus1269) Saureus1364_00430(Saureus1364) Saureus170_00571(Saureus170) Saureus170_00574(Saureus170) Saureus302_00352(Saureus302) Saureus302_00556(Saureus302) Saureus71193_01311(Saureus71193) Saureus71193_01312(Saureus71193) Saureus71193_01314(Saureus71193) SaureusED98_01423(SaureusED98) SaureusED98_01426(SaureusED98) SaureusLGA251_01423(SaureusLGA251) SaureusN305_02185(SaureusN305) SaureusN305_02187(SaureusN305) SaureusST398_01477(SaureusST398) SaureusST398_01478(SaureusST398) SaureusST398_01548(SaureusST398) SaureusED133_01465(SaureusED133) Saureus302_01433(Saureus302)
```

Req.Output

```
Saureus1000 Saureus08BA02176_00020
```

I am using this code to find but not getting the required output in single line

```
awk '{print $1} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^Saureus08BA/){print $i}}}' file > test
```

Output for this command

```
Saureus1000(37
Saureus08BA02176_00020(Saureus08BA02176)
Saureus08BA02176_01763(Saureus08BA02176)
Saureus08BA02176_01805(Saureus08BA02176)
Saureus08BA02176_01808(Saureus08BA02176)
Saureus1001(35
Saureus08BA02176_01441(Saureus08BA02176)
Saureus08BA02176_01442(Saureus08BA02176)
Saureus08BA02176_01443(Saureus08BA02176)
Saureus08BA02176_01445(Saureus08BA02176)
```

Comment: `Saureus08BA` is matching in both the input lines, how do you expect it for only first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU ***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'match($0,/^([^(]+)\([^(]+(Saureus08BA[0-9]+_[0-9]+)/,a){ print a[1],a[2] }' file
```

- `([^(]+)` - capturing the needed part from the 1st field
- `(Saureus08BA[0-9]+_[0-9]+)` - the 2nd captured group containing the next "*Saureus*" item

The output:

```
Saureus1000 Saureus08BA02176_00020
Saureus1001 Saureus08BA02176_01441
```